# How can you color NAnt output?

Tags: command-line, colors, nant

We are looking at using NAnt as a deployment tool for our internal (usually web based) applications.

One of our (many) current solutions uses colored output on the commandline to indicate if there was a problem with the installation (green and red).

Is there an easy way to change the output to be a particular color when NAnt is executing.

If there is no easy way, I'd be interested in hearing good ways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We ended up making a custom task called colorecho which works the same as the echo task but let us color the output it makes.

Comment: are you able to tell us how you did that at all? I'm looking to do a simialr thing.

Comment: http://riccardotramma.com/tag/nant/ looks like it could be useful here.  There's no source, but you can use JetBrains' dotPeek to decompile it and repurpose I suppose.

Comment: I have tested this and its works fine NAnt 0.92 (Build 0.92.4543.0; release; 9/06/2012)

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried this yet, but the following link looks promising:

[Colorized-NAnt-Console-Output](http://twericliu.blogspot.com/2008/03/colorized-nant-console-output.html)

Comment: Of course, that requires patching and building the Nant source.

Comment: I like it.  I will have to try it.  It would be nice if it could just compile to a separate DLL that could be dropped in to a standard NAnt install, and then the logger made available via configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the NAnt Tool: [ColorNAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/external.html) ([direct link](http://colornant.googlepages.com/))?

Comment: I saw it in the list but I wasn't interested in running PERL... looking through it tho.